# Can I power a router that requires 12V-DC via a 5,5mm input by using a powerbank that can output 12V DC over USB

Tags: usb, 12v, router

I have a powerbank that can output 5V-3A/9V-2A/12V-1,5A over USB. The router I would like to power came with a 12V-1A adapter and uses less than 12W. If I were to buy a USB to 5,5mm adapter cable, would my powerbank be able to power this router? How would the powerbank know it has to output 12V? The powerbank is a MOJOGEAR XL MG-09.

Thanks in advance!
Gerjan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some active device that will communicate with the USB-PD controller in the power bank, triggering it to output 12V.

I won't make any specific product recommendations, but if you search for "USB PD 12V trigger" using your favorite Internet search engine, you will find multiple devices that do this.

Comment: +1 on what @Jack said, unless you have a dumb enough powerbank to give out 12 V without handshaking.